# Should I continue to use xCode 4.2, iPhone 3.1.3 workarounds to expose performance issues?

Tags: performance, testing, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode4.2

I'm writing in xCode 4.2 using the latest SDKs, but I want to do testing on an old iPhone 2G (3.1.3 iOS) device. The purpose of this is to get a stronger performance metric. Ultimately, I understand that the appStore may no longer be accepting 3.x applications. But performing a slower test like this can help:

1. tighten up loops to speeds things up
2. make code more efficient by identifying good places to multi-thread
3. (**most Importantly**) reduce load time, like Default.png tricks, and loading dialogs

My question, should I:

- Forget about this, it's too difficult with all the cross-compatibility issues between iOS 4.x and iOS 3.x. Better to simply "scale the timestamps of NSLog" on an iPhone 3G (4.2 iOS) instead of an iPhone 2G (3.1.3 iOS).
- Keep going, just keep using backwards compatible code and workarounds.
- Only consider this if you don't plan to use: ***_*__*_*__** classes (what are they from your experience?)

I've been toying with this for a while: so here's what I have run into so far:

1. Under xCode 4.2, you need to add "armv6" on all static libraries and app projects using the "+" under "Project->Settings->Architectures" make sure not to remove "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT".
2. I have some run-time specific code, added checks:

   ```
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   if ([now respondsToSelector:@selector(dateByAddingTimeInterval:)])
   {
      //iOS 4.0
   }
   else 
   {
      //iOS 3.1.3
   }
   ```
3. Can also do pre-compiler flags:

   ```
   #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_3_1
   #else
   #endif
   ```
4. Can also dynamically check the version:

   ```
   float version = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
   if (version > 3.1.3)
   {
       //do stuff
   }
   ```

It's a lot of additional work. Anyone have advise on this? Is there a better way? Is there a list similar to the above of DOs and DONTs for this? What worked for you and save you the most time/money?

Comment: Went to iPhone 3G 4.2.1 at the moment, but would be really nice to develop on a slower device for extra tuning purposes.